# How do I use a column separated field within in clause

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I use a column separated field within `in` clause

```
Table 1 (id,requestedColor) 
Data  
1     Red,Green,Black,Orannge,
2    Blue,
3    Yellow,Red,

table 2 (colorname)
Data
Red
Pink
Green
```

I need to find all colors from `table 2` for a given `requestedColumn` (from `table 1`).

Comment: This is a horrible database design.  You should explain why you have a bogus design -- especially when Oracle supports nested tables, JSON, and XML which are a bit better for storing such information.

Comment: Or even just regular tables :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with an `IN` condition, at least not directly. What comes in parentheses in the `IN` condition should be a list of several separate strings, separated with commas. What you have in your first table (in each row) is a single string - what is in it (the fact that it contains commas, for example) is entirely irrelevant.

There are three ways to do this. One is - the best advice - to fix your data model. Do not hold several values in a single field; this is a violation of the absolute minimum requirement for sound table design, known as "First Normal Form".

Failing that, you could split the strings and then use `IN` in the normal way.

For this particular exercise, it may be easier to have conditions like

```
... where ',' || table1.requestedcolor || ',' like '%,' || table2.colorname || ',%'
```

The concatenated commas are necessary to avoid situations like `Red` matching `Dark Red`, etc.

Regardless of which approach you choose (short of the correct one, which is to normalize your table), the code will be both difficult to read, write and maintain, and inefficient. There's no way around it. This is why professionals are so adamant about First Normal Form in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. I cant make change in table model. however <where ',' || table1.requestedcolor || ',' like '%,' || table2.colorname || ',%'> is really a smart idea  and it really helped!! Thanks a ton!! I have a complex business need and this is the best I could explain (data and format remains the same). I needed to add a column in SQL which would be yes if 'requested color' from Table 1 exists in Table 2. Thanks again

Comment: @RaviSharma - if you find that performance is unacceptable (depending on the amount of data to process), and if table1 is relatively small while table2 (or its equivalent) has millions of rows or more, it may still be better to split the strings from table1 (there are many threads on StackOverflow explaining how that's done), even **within** a single SQL SELECT statement. Keep that in mind in case you need it.

Comment: I tried with split but then I was unable to use it in subquery. Select <bunch of select cols from diff tables>, case 
when exists (Select 1 from table2 where colorname in 
(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(requestedColor, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS "single_col_name" 
    FROM  (
         SELECT ROWNUM AS ids
          ,      requestedColor     FROM   T1
       )
  CONNECT BY INSTR(requestedColor, ',', 1, LEVEL-1) > 0
   )
) then 'yes' else 'no'
from <bunch of tables and join>
inner join table1 T1 <some cndition> 
It was unable to find T1. replacing the <case when exists query> with yours worked

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what @mathguy said; another (potentially inefficient) method is to use a regular expression for the join:

```
select t2.colorname
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on regexp_like(t1.requestedColor, '(^|,)' || t2.colorname || '(,|$)')
where t1.id = 1

COLORNAME
---------
Red
Green
```

Comment: Nitpick: logically I understand the preference for `(^|,)`, but - since regular expressions with alternations are tried in the order of the tokens in the alternation - for efficiency it is better to put the more likely match candidate first. `(,|^)` and `(,|$)` seem to me to be the better choices in all cases.

Comment: I had that and swapped it, not sure why. Hadn't thought about it in terms of efficiency, so good to know.

Comment: Regular expressions are generally more computationally expensive than simpler alternatives, such as mathguy's 'like' approach - compare both, it may not be significiant for your real data volumes. Everything's a trade-off. Most efficient would be fixing your data model, of course *8-)